# When I write my server ip on browser I get the following output :

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, centos7, cpanel

While accessing my server with ip in browser I get the following output :

http://example.com/wp-admin/install.php

[image: output]

Can anyone help me to detect the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

what you want the output to be?
It seems that you have placed wordpress setup on the web root folder. you can install wordpress and build your site on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is all ok with your apache server. It seems that you have Wordpress installed and this is the setup screen for it. If you want  that the browser shows something else when you type in the servers ip, you have to place some other files in the sites folder. I think it is in */var/www*